# ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement - cannot determine what is wrong

Tags: sql, oracle, insert-into, ora-00900

I try to Execute the following:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (select * from IT_IMAGES where IT_CODE='8717163044612') 
  BEGIN 
     INSERT INTO IT_IMAGES (LARGE_IMG,SMALL_IMG,IT_CODE,LAN_CODE) VALUES ('7290011051310.jpg','7290011051310.jpg','8717163044612','1')
  END
```

But I keep getting ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement . Can you help me fix this?

Comment: Are you running this inside a stored procedure, trigger, function, or PL/SQL block?  Or are you just running this code inside, say, toad?

Comment: Im using direct sql with TOAD

Comment: Your code works fine for me on SQL Server. Is that what you have posted here your full query, or is there more to it?

Answer (score 1):

The following should work for you:

```
 INSERT INTO IT_IMAGES(LARGE_IMG, SMALL_IMG, IT_CODE, LAN_CODE)
    SELECT '7290011051310.jpg', '7290011051310.jpg', '8717163044612', '1'
    FROM dual
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM IT_IMAGES WHERE IT_CODE = '8717163044612');
```

As I think about it, I haven't used `if` except in `begin`/`end` statements in Oracle.  You may need a programming block to use `if` (MySQL does require this).  The above should fix the problem, though.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f3316/1) is an example of it working in SQL Fiddle.

Comment: mmm... I tried this and now I get ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: It works in SQL Fiddle (see the link in the answer).

Comment: Yes, in Oracle you can only use conditional logic in a PL/SQL block, not in plain SQL.

Comment: @AlexPoole . . . Thank you for the confirmation.